# Connect iPhone to local server for testing on XCode? -- without using WiFi

Tags: ios, xcode, ejabberd

So I have an ejabberd (XMPP) server setup on my MacBook. Connects fine with Simulator, only intermittently on the device. The two times it hasn't connected were at cafes that had sign-on gateways for their Wi-Fi. I know nothing when it comes to networks, but I'm guessing this is a Firewall thing?

I'm supposing I can't get around the firewall without an elaborate workaround.

I've found that turning off Wi-Fi on both devices and turning on tethering so that both devices are communicating via data works. However, I'd rather not do this as my data plan is limited and I'd like to be freely internet-connected while I work.

Is there a way to setup XCode to have the phone use the USB connection to access the server on the MacBook? Or maybe some other way I'm not imagining?

Bluetooth doesn't work.

Comment: When you are at the café, booth the MacBook and the device are connected to the same network, right?
And what's the IP addr you are putting in your code to connect to the MacBook? Is it a local IP?

Comment: @CEAFDC Both are connected to the same network. I'm using this line:         `[xmppStream setHostName:@"Macintosh-8.local"];` It has worked as is at a cafe without a sign-on gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the problem is with some kind of firewall on the network…
Try using the local IP address instead of the hostname, It will change from network to network. To get it, you can open the network utility

[image: netutil]

In this case it would be `[xmppStream setHostName:@"172.16.1.2"];`

Comment: I did try sticking the IP address in there at one point. Maybe I had some other settings wrong. I'll try this again when the issue comes up again.

Comment: OK, so I'm finally at a cafe where it isn't working, and this cafe has a sign-on gateway. Using the IP address for `setHostName` doesn't work. =(.